# Grant access to admin menu?

Tags: user-roles, admin-menu, capabilities

I'm trying to grant the user role 'editor' to have access to the Users top-level menu, and then control which sub-menus they have access to. The add_action lives in the _construct method.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'action_admin_menu' ) );

public function action_admin_menu() {
        $edit_contributor = get_role( 'editor' );
        $edit_contributor->add_cap( 'edit_users' );
    }
```

I'm expecting the Users menu to appear for an Editor, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I am not claiming this is a canonical list but the user related capabilities I see are:

- `add_users`
- `create_users`
- `delete_users`
- `edit_users`
- `list_users`
- `promote_users`
- `remove_users`

I got this working with only `list_users` and `edit_users`. I did test all combinations of those, just a few obvious ones. Of course, you may want more capabilities than that.

Comment: What hook did you use: admin_menu or admin_init? The editor had access to the Users menu?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, this was a caching issue.

Comment: I didn't use a hook. I used a plugin to mess with the capabilities. Sorry, I thought the issue was only with "which capability" not with the broader `hook` function.